# Java Splitting Arraylist from Map

Tags: java, json, arraylist, dictionary

I have an arraylist obtained from mp as follows,

```
ArrayList<String> aList = (ArrayList<String>) jsonMap.get("govIds");
```

the size of arraylist is 1 and its contents is as fooles,

```
[{govId=023402094, govIdType=TEST}]
```

How to make the size of arraylist as 2 with govId=023402094 as one string object and govIdType=TEST as another string object.

or How to make [{govId=023402094, govIdType=TEST}] as a key(String)-value(String)(again a map) pair.

Thanks

Comment: What type/class do you want to use for `govId=023402084`?  That looks like a tuple to me, rather than a primitive.

Comment: it can be string type

Comment: Does the list has to be format of xxx=yyy, can it possible to be xxx:yyy?

Comment: @tjkmr, OK, check my answer to see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    //here is the test data
    String s="[{govId=023402094, govIdType=TEST}]";
    List<String> aList =new ArrayList<String>();
    aList.add(s);
    //end of test data

    //Here is what you need begins   
    String text=aList.get(0).replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "");// remove the char "{","}","[" and "]"
    //now the text is :govId=023402094, govIdType=TEST

    String[] values=text.split(",");
    List resultList=new ArrayList<String>();//Convert to another list, you can if you want to change a little to change into a map
    for(String value:values){
        resultList.add(value);
    }

   //test the result
    System.out.println(resultList);//[govId=023402094,  govIdType=TEST]
```

If you your string format can looks like a JSON {key1:value, key2:value2}; you can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to easily change it into a map:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s="[{govId:023402094, govIdType:TEST}]";// something like this
    String text=s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");// remove the char "[" and "]" to make it like as JSON format

    Map<String,String> map=toMapUsingGSON(text));

}

private static Map<String,String> toMapUsingGSON(String json){
    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();  
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, mapType);
}
```